# Way from config.yml to Symfony controller

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I have question about `Symfony` container. I tried to find some informations about how variables are returned.

For example, `config.yml` to my controller, where I want get this value.

Question: *config.yml*

```
my_var: 12345
```

Controller: *DefaultController.php*

```
public function testAction(){

    die($this->get('my_var'));

}
```

How does the `controller` get the value of `my_var`?

Comment: you may want to put that `my_var` under `parameter`, and get that with `getParameter('my_var')` of the container instance

Answer (score 1):

Your custom parameter has to live in the parameters domain of your config.yml

```
# config.yml
parameters:
    locale: en
    my_var: 12345
```

Then you can use the container method `getParameter()` inside your code.
That is if the container is available.

```
$this->container->getParameter('my_var')
```

Inside a class extending `Controller.php` (or any other class implementing  ContainerInterface) you can simply write

`$this->getParameter('my_var')` which in turn calls the method above inside the super class.

[Introduction to parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html)

[Best practices for configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html)